# CSS font ignored with Copy / Paste

Tags: html, css, font-face, copy-paste

I have the following code. It displays correctly in all four cases. However, when the divs are copied (right click / copy) and pasted into a Word document, the fonts for the four divs are, in order: `Times`, `Trebuchet`, `Courier`, `Trebuchet`.

The font is only recognized with an inline style set. Any idea why the `css` font is ignored with `copy`? More importantly, can I fix this in my css or do I have explicitly set the font with inline code in every case?

It's also interesting that the default for the `<pre>` is `Courier` but for the `<div>` is `Times`(both the default for my browser and MS Word). I could almost live with the output if `<pre>` didn't give me `Courier`.

```
<style>
pre {font-family:"trebuchet ms",arial,sans-serif;}

.test {font-family:"trebuchet ms",arial,sans-serif;}
</style>

<div class="test">
Test of div with css set font
</div>

<div class="test" style="font-family:'trebuchet ms',arial,sans-serif">
Test of div with inline font
</div>


<div>
<pre>
Test of pre with css set font
</pre>
</div>

<div>
<pre style="font-family:'trebuchet ms', arial, sans-serif">
Test of pre with inline font
</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether the fonts Trebuchet, Courier are in there in your System Fonts. 
Check here:Control Panel > Fonts
Only the fonts present in this folder maintain themselves while copy/paste in MS-Word

Comment: They did show up when the fonts were specified with inline css. The issue is not with missing fonts.